# Reshaping a wav file to 8000Hz

Tags: python, python-3.8, librosa

I am developing an ML model, here I try to read a `sample_wav.wav` file and provide the data into the `predict` function to predict an output.

### python_model.py

```py
import librosa
import numpy as np

# Python and TensorFlow ML model
[...]

# sample_wav.wav sample rate : 44100 Hz
path_to_sample_wav='../sample-wavs/sample_wav.wav'

samples, sample_rate = librosa.load(path_to_sample_wav, sr = 44100)
print(sample_rate)
print(type(samples))
print(samples.shape)

print('resampling process:-------------- ')
samples = librosa.resample(samples, orig_sr=sample_rate, target_sr=8000)
print(samples.shape)
```

#### Actual output:

```
44100
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
(52992,)
resampling process:-------------- 
(9614,)
```

#### Expected output:

- There is a `training_record_01.wav` file. This file worked fine with the `predict(audio)` function with no issues.
  `Sample rate`: `16000 Hz`
  `samples.shape` shows `(8000,)`

```
16000
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
(16000,)
resampling process:-------------- 
(8000,)
```

##### predict function

```py
def predict(audio):
    prob=model.predict(audio.reshape(1,8000,1))
    index=np.argmax(prob[0])
    return classes[index]
```

How can I reshape the `sample_wav.wav` file as the expected output, if it's possible? I hope to call the `predict(audio)` function and pass the audio data and get the output.

Currently, I am having the following issue when using predict function:

```py
print("Text:",predict(samples))

# issue

ValueErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-198-5637a981cc7f> in <module>
----> 1 print("Text:",predict(samples))

<ipython-input-147-213bc78e946a> in predict(audio)
      1 def predict(audio):
----> 2     prob=model.predict(audio.reshape(1,8000,1))
      3     index=np.argmax(prob[0])
      4     return classes[index]

ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 9614 into shape (1,8000,1)
```

FYI: librosa v0.8.1

Comment: I don't understand the issue. Your audio is more than 1 second long, so at 8000 Hz it will have more than 8000 samples. You could use `audio.reshape((1, -1, 1))` instead.

Comment: @xdurch0, Please note that I updated the question with the issue that I currently face. If the `sample_wav.wav` file is more than one second what are the changes I can do to make use of this predict function?